# change hotkey (shortcut) for Intel Graphic control panel 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, intel-graphics

i need to change reserved hotkey in Intel graphic so i can use them in PyCharm . by default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd> used in Intel Graphic so i need to change them in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.in windows simply can open `Intel graphic control panel` and change them but i can't found any clear way in Ubuntu. since i'm a new in Linux please explain somehow to get to know.

thank you

Comment: What does the hotkey currently do? I would be surprised if this hotkey would be defined system wide for a graphical card. Conventionally this hotkey is used to switch horizontal workspaces (and still is defined as such), but Ubuntu only has vertically oriented workspaces, so they have no effect.

Comment: @vanadium exactly your word is true . i'm new in Linux and i just thinking same like a Windows  again Intel Graphic reserved that hotkey  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default in Ubuntu 17.10 and up (Ubuntu versions using Gnome Shell), the keybindings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right/Left</kbd> are set to switch to the left or the right workspace. In Ubuntu (with Gnome Shell), they do not have effect because Gnome Shell by default only features vertically arranged workspaces. Still, they still are defined for this function, and thus are not working in applications that also define these key combinations. Desktop wide defined hotkeys indeed have priority over hotkeys defined at the application level.

To release these keys, remove their assignment. You can use dconf-editor (not installed by default), or use the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "['']"
```

Now, the keys are not anymore claimed by the desktop environment and will now work in applications that have given them a function.

Alternatively, you can now also assign them your own desktop-wide function through "Settings" - "Keyboard".

Comment: Thank You sir . finally someone have a clear answer on this question. again thank you very much sir.